# Jquery hover to only have effect for certain amount of time

Tags: jquery, timer, hover, mouseover

I'm using a jquery hover effect but would only like the effect to last for around a second when rolled over....ie user rolls over image, it changes for a second, then reverts back to the original image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$(function() {
    $('.rollover').hover(function() {
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover'));
        $(this).attr('hover', currentImg);
    }, function() {
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover'));
        $(this).attr('hover', currentImg);
    });
});
```

});

This is the code I'm using for the standard hover. 
Any help would be great, thanks.

As an update, I'm still having trouble implementing this code...I imagine the setTimeout function should be added somewhere here

```
 }, function() {
    var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover'));
    $(this).attr('hover', currentImg);
});
```

but I'm just not sure how to implement it properly.

Some help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `setTimeout` method in `hover` callback method to restore back to original image after a second.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm new to js so not really sure how to implement the setTimeout method. I'll look in to it, thanks.

Comment: This article by John Resig explains it well, http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/